# QtreeView: update content without scrolling it up

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm mapping the content of a `QMap<QString, QMap<QString,int>>` to a `QStandardItemModel` which connected to `QTreeView` (where each key in the map is the root of the items in the sub-QMap).

When the content of this map is changing by other part of my app (every few seconds), I need to update the `QTreeView` as well. I can reset the model and fill it again with the updated data, but then the tree is being 'refreshed'; it's scrolled up and the root items are collapsed, and this is a bad user experience.

I found a QT sample of a custom model based on `QAbstractItemModel` [here (Chapter 10, Figure 10.14)](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/files/c-gui-programming-with-qt-4-2ndedition.pdf) and the behavior on data-changed is the same.

Any idea how to update the content without refreshing the treeview?

Answer (score -1):

> I can reset the model and fill it again with the updated data, but then the tree is being 'refreshed'; it's scrolled up and the root items are collapsed, and this is a bad user experience.

And that's precisely why you should NOT reset the model, rather use the fine grained signals/modifications that the Qt Model/View APIs offer:

- `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged`
- `QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows` / `QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows`
- `QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertColumns` / `QAbstractItemModel::endInsertColumns`

and so on. Now if you're using the convenience `QStandardItemModel` class, and manage it properly (for instance, by creating/destroying/modifying branches via the corresponding `QStandardItem`s), then the views will be well-behaved and will not lose selection or position.

Otherwise, you'll need to come up with workarounds, such as "remembering" the expanded state / scroll position / selection; or comparing the new data structure with the old one, finding the differences, and updating the model; etc.

Comment: How should I use the APIs you mentioned except "comparing the new data structure with the old one, finding the differences, and updating the model"?

Comment: It depends on the underlying storage of your data. If you "just" get a brand new map (and not notifications of changes) then you have no other choice of trying to detect the changes yourself and update the model class accordingly.